# How do I set focus follows mouse in Ubuntu 17.10 and later with GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome, mouse, window, gnome-tweak-tool, focus

I found multiple answers on askUbuntu about this topic. But none of them suites to Ubuntu 17.10.
So I need to ask again:

How do I set focus follows mouse in Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1726195 (for me, seems broken specifically when switching from unity to gnome, and/or to 17.10 and wayland): I'm used to using "sloppy" focus following mouse, but I still expect alt-tab to set focus to the selected window, but in 17.10, it's necessary to actually move the mouse to the window (and let it stop, then keep it there)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You may use *(GNOME) Tweaks* to achieve your goal. If it's not installed, first install it by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Launch Tweaks and go to the *Windows* section. Select "*Sloppy*" or "*Secondary-Click*" under *Window Focus*.

[image]

Alternatively you may run the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode 'sloppy'
```

etc.

Comment: Is there a way to set it to change focus as soon as the mouse enters the window, rather than when the mouse stops moving?

Comment: What a sloppy UI!  Looks like checkboxes, and looks disabled to boot!  Is actually radio-button-like.  Click on the one you want, ignore your instinctive urge to untick the ticked one.

Comment: I've confirmed that gnome-tweaks work on Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish). Choose "Secondary Click" and it will work.

Comment: _The joy of Linux_: change the OSs behaviour by a simple switch. Customize it as you please.

Comment: Is it also 18.04 safe? :-)

Comment: @matt Should work fine.

Comment: FWIW worked for me on 18.04 (though, I tried the `gsettings` first and while that seemed to toggle the setting it didn't actually change the behavior)

Comment: For whoever cares, the `gsettings` command also works in Fedora 32.

Comment: @DominickPastore to make the focus change immediate run `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter focus-change-on-pointer-rest false`

Comment: Is the opposite possible? I.e.: Move the mouse to window automatically when changing windows with the keyboard, for example with `alt+tab` or `Super+1-9`?