# How to bring back "sloppy focus" in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: mouse, 19.04

"Sloppy focus" is such a great productivity helper but Ubuntu 19.04 seems to have removed it.

The new "focus on hover" option (available from gnome tweak) means if I Alt-Tab to another app but my mouse is still over the old window then the old window immediately receives focus again - so Alt-Tab becomes useless!

Is there some way to get the previous behaviour back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's available in gnome-tweaks.

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then run

```
gnome-tweaks
```

Go to "Windows" -> "Window focus"

[image: gnome-tweaks]

and you're probably looking for "Secondary-Click" option.

Comment: Thanks! Wow that text is misleading "secondary-click" (?) and the text below in grey doesn't describe it either! There's still some bugs I think; e.g. with this secondary click option I can't raise the focussed window by clicking - unless I click the titlebar or hold the Window Action Key down and *then* click. Anyway I suppose that's a different question.

Comment: Yeah, consistency is not a strong point of the GNOME developers.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 (or at least the PopOS variant) "Focus on Hover" and "Secondary-Click" also raise the window to the front, even when "Raise Windows When Focused" is *not* selected in Ubuntu Tweaks there.  Any way to only focus, and not raise to front, in the latest Ubuntu?

Comment: In ubuntu 22.10 (gnome 43.0, wayland) this no longer works (I'd previously upvoted this as working years ago). Currently, same problem OP describes exists: " I Alt-Tab to another app but my mouse is still over the old window then the old window immediately receives focus again - so Alt-Tab becomes useless!" (There was a gnome extension hack but it also doesn't work anymore.)  I'm really frustrated with Gnome (for 20+ years) and keep going back to KDE for the simplest features.

Comment: related, but just like the answer below, no longer works (ubuntu 22.10) https://askubuntu.com/a/978404/17060