# How do you configure such that window focus follows the mouse in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, focus

How do you configure so that window focus goes to the window under the mouse position? I see only answers relating to arcane versions of Ubuntu. [Should you install the gnome tweak tool](https://askubuntu.com/a/978404/208696)? is it officially supported?

Comment: You linked to the right duplicate question. Indeed, by default, the setting is not exposed to the user in Gnome Shell. You change a dconf key or use Tweaks.

Comment: Generally whatever you can do with GUI Gnome Tweaks you can also do directly from command line with `gsetrings`. The advantage is it is automatically installed by default.

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode 'sloppy'
`